# Structures in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have some code in C with uses structures through out the code.
I mostly use memset or memcpy to copy the data from/to buffer.

Wanted to know will this work in C++ ?. '
As per MSDN :

> In C++, a structure is the same as a class except that its members are
>   public by default.

So that means C++ compiler will insert the internals in to the structure object and memset or memcpy will not work as in C.

Also, is 'this' pointer applicable to structure also and is there any way i can stop the compiler from inserting anything C++ish in to my object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your structures don't use any C++ constructs(virtualism etc), `memcpy` and `memset` will work on them even in C++.

**Also, is 'this' pointer applicable to structure?**
Yes, the `this` pointer is applicable to the structure as it is for a class.

**Is there any way i can stop the compiler from inserting anything C++ish in to my object ?**
The compiler won't unless you use any C++ constructs to your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `memXXXX` at will, as long as your `struct` (or `class`) contains only ordinal data types or structures/classes consisting of those, without non-trivial c'tors/d'tors (constructors/destructors).

The even fact is this a `class` or a `struct` - doesn't matter.

Comment: I think no virtual function would also be a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some code in C with uses structures through out the code. I mostly use memset or memcpy to copy the data from/to buffer.
>
> Wanted to know will this work in C++ ?. ' As per MSDN :
>
> In C++, a structure is the same as a class except that its members are public by default.

Yes - MSDN is correct, but that doesn't mean that copying a C++ `class` is as safe as copying a C `struct`, rather that structs can be as complex as classes and neither is safe in general.  You should definitely prefer to move to use properly default/copy constructed objects and ditch the `memset`/`memcpy` operations.  While `memset` and `memcpy` can work in limited cases (basically, when the `class`/`struct` and all its bases contains only stuff that would have worked in C (a pointer to the virtual dispatch table will not be properly set by memset, but may work after a `memcpy` - all implementation-defined), and doesn't try to maintain any invariants.  In practice, classes often have invariants or introduce them as they become more self-managing, encapsulating units of code/data: the constructors may ensure some data members have related, consistent, expected values - without these invariants being kept true - and memset is likely to invalidate all but the simplest of them - the class may exhibit undefined behaviour later.

> Also, is 'this' pointer applicable to structure also and is there any way i can stop the compiler from inserting anything C++ish in to my object ?

Yes - again a `struct` in C++ is the same kind of entity as a `class` - the only differences are in the visibility/accessibility of member functions and data.  Both have `this` pointers.  But, this pointers are not stored in classes/structs - they are pointers to such objects implicitly provided to calls to member functions.  You do not have to worry about this in the context of (ab)using `memcpy` and `memset`.  More generally, the only C++ specific things you have to worry about is `virtual` functions and class invariants that may be invalidated.  You still have to worry about the C issues: `memcpy` creating multiple objects using the same resources (file descriptors, pointers to heap, locks, etc.) where both objects assume they have exclusive control of that resource and attempt to delete/free/release it later.

Answer (score 0):

> So that means C++ compiler will insert the internals in to the
>   structure object

No it doesn't.

> and memset or memcpy will not work as in C.

It doesn't mean that either.

Your guesses are entirely unmotivated, and your question remains unclear.